# Listview formatting

Tags: excel, vba

Can some one please advise as to what is wrong in my code. I want to format the amount column (Column B).

```
ListItems(lv_item).ListSubItems.Add , , FormatNumber(ws1.Range("B" & pos), "#,###,##0")
```

Comment: In VBA it should just be Format(ws1.Range("B" & pos), "#,###,##0") and not FormatNumber.  Give that a try.

Comment: That is simply not true @legendjr.  `FormatNumber` is available, supported and useful.  See  https://support.office.com/en-in/article/FormatNumber-Function-91030eab-2887-43d4-9c17-311ab6ebf43b

Comment: thanks @joehanna.  I learned something new today.

Comment: It's always good to learn something new :-). If my answer below solved your problem, please mark it as accepted for future visitors to this post.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using `FormatNumber` in VBA.  Its job is to take your number and apply the locale-based rules for formatting (000's separators etc) as defined in the Regional Settings Number tab.  You can optionally supply the number of decimal places to this function.

Your function call should be simply:-

```
'Format number according to system locale and ensure zero decimal places
FormatNumber(ws1.Range("B" & pos), 0)
```

Check this Microsoft Support page out for more information: https://support.office.com/en-in/article/FormatNumber-Function-91030eab-2887-43d4-9c17-311ab6ebf43b